# Smooth proper scheme over Z

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Does every smooth proper morphism $X \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathbf{Z}$ with $X$ nonempty have a section?

**EDIT** [Bjorn gave additional information in a comment below, which I am recopying here.  -- Pete L. Clark]

Here are some special cases, according to the relative dimension $d$. If $d=0$, a positive answer follows from Minkowski's theorem that every nontrivial finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}$  ramifies at at least one prime. If $d=1$, it is a consequence (via taking the Jacobian) of the theorem of Abrashkin and Fontaine that there is no nonzero abelian scheme over $\mathbf{Z}$, together with (for the genus $0$ case) the fact that a quaternion algebra over $\mathbf{Q}$ split at every finite place is trivial.

Comment: Could you provide us with a bit of motivation, background, etc. to this question?

Comment: I don't know of any examples of smooth proper varieties over $\mathbf{Z}$, except those constructed in some simple way from the flag varieties of Chevalley groups. Does anyone know other interesting examples? Also, the answer to your question is certainly NO if one replaces the integers by the ring of integers in a suitable number field. Do you know some variant of the question that might remain true?

Comment: Here are some special cases, according to the relative dimension $d$.  If $d=0$, a positive answer follows from Minkowski's theorem that every nontrivial finite extension of $\mathbf{Q}$ ramifies at at least one prime.  If $d=1$, it is a consequence (via taking the Jacobian) of the theorem of Abrashkin and Fontaine that there is no nonzero abelian scheme over $\mathbf{Z}$, together with (for the genus $0$ case) the fact that a quaternion algebra over $\mathbf{Q}$ split at every finite place is trivial.


Comment: I think your deleting your answer represents a net loss to the community! What do you think the etale cohomology of the "E_8 hypersurface" looks like? Note that I get around Hasse Principle issues by letting the variety have no real points ;-)

Comment: It looks like a great question with a great answer.  Can someone help me out by explaining what it means for a scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$ to be smooth, and to have a section?


Comment: Greg: A section is the obvious thing: a morphism $\text{Spec}\mathbb{Z} \to X$ such that $\text{Spec}\mathbb{Z} \to X \to \text{Spec}\mathbb{Z}$ is the identity morphism. Smooth morphisms are explained for example on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_scheme_theory#Smooth_morphisms

Comment: Regarding the cohomology of the E_8 hypersurface, it's all generated by the class of the hyperplane section. (This assuming I've correctly unpacked the theorems on cohomology of complete intersections.) So it has the same cohomology as P^7.

Comment: @Kevin:  Thanks, you gave me a good mini-answer.


Comment: @James Borger: I disagree. If Q is the split quadric in P^7, then H^6(Q) is two dimensional, and only one dimension is generated by restriction from P^7. The same should be true for the E_8 quadric, right? 

Comment: By the way, I've been trying to work out the Galois action on this H^6. I get that complex conjugation acts with eigenvalues (1,-1); and every odd Frobenius acts trivially. I haven't been able to work out what the Frobenius at 2 does, though.

Comment: @David Speyer: Oh, you're right! Thanks. (I made a parity error. A form in n-variables defines a variety of dimension n-2, not n-1. So, as you point out, there is an extra dimension in the middle cohomology.)

Comment: If every odd Frobenius acts trivially, then the Galois representation is trivial, by Chebatorev's Density Theorem.

Comment: I am naive but I still want to ask: in the case $d=1$, you said "via taking Jacobians", can you elaborate a little more, for example why all fibers have the same genus?(you are not able to apply the flat base theorem here.) And secondly, why does the relative Picard scheme must be a Abelian scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$? Does the same argument implies that any proper smooth scheme over $\mathbb{Z}$ have a trivial Picard scheme?

Comment: @Yuan Yang: Smooth implies flat.  The relative Jacobian ($\operatorname{Pic}^0$, not Pic) is an abelian scheme: WLOG the relative curve is connected; then the fibers are geometrically connected since there is no nontrivial finite étale cover of Spec $\mathbb{Z}$, so Prop. 4 on p. 260 of Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud applies.  In your last sentence, in the higher-dimensional case, I will assume that by "trivial Picard scheme" you meant "trivial $\operatorname{Pic}^0$"; the argument seems incomplete, however, since it's not obvious a priori that $\operatorname{Pic}^0$ is an abelian scheme.

Comment: @BjornPoonen Thanks! Sorry for my abuse of $Pic$ and $Pic^0$...The reference to the Neron Model book is really helpful. But I am still confused about this flat base change. In our case, don't we need $spec F_p\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ to be flat, and $H^1(X,O_X)$ is torsion free? (I want to use prop 9.3,chap 3 in Hartshorne's book )But this is obviously not flat. Are you using the fact that $Pic^0_{X/\mathbb{Z}}$ is already an abelian scheme?

Comment: @Yuan Yang: You could use Hartshorne III.9.10 instead, at least if you are willing to assume that $X$ is projective over $\mathbb{Z}$ (which is true: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/207443 for an even more general statement).

Comment: @BjornPoonen Ah!!! You are so right !

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Hey Bjorn. Let me try for a counterexample. Consider a hypersurface in projective $N$-space, defined by one degree 2 equation with integral coefficients. When is such a gadget smooth? Well the partial derivatives are all linear and we have $N+1$ of them, so we want some $(N+1)$ times $(N+1)$ matrix to have non-zero determinant mod $p$ for all $p$, so we want the determinant to be +-1. The determinant we're taking is that of a symmetric matrix with even entries down the diagonal (because the derivative of $X^2$ is $2X$) and conversely every symmetric integer matrix with even entries down the diagonal comes from a projective quadric hypersurface. So aren't we now looking for a positive-definite (to stop there being any Q-points or R-points) even unimodular lattice?

So in conclusion I think that the hypersurface cut out by the quadratic form associated in this way to e.g. the $E_8$ lattice or the Leech lattice gives a counterexample!

Comment: This is such a nice example that it should be a standard one.

Comment: The reason the answer is written "I think that..." and "aren't we..." is precisely because it came out so nicely and I'd never seen it before, so was almost certain I'd made a slip!

Comment: Nice example! Stupid generalization:  this is a flag variety of a reductive group over $\mathbf{Z}$; one gets a similar example from any such that is compact over $\mathbf{R}$, see Gross' paper for a list.  

Comment: That's beautiful, Kevin!  
One comment: If the determinant is $\pm 1$, then the projective quadric hypersurface is smooth over $\mathbf{Z}$, but not conversely.  For example, if $f(x_1,\ldots,x_8)$ is the $E_8$ quadratic form, then $f(x_1,\ldots,x_8)+x_9^2=0$ in $\mathbf{P}^8$ works too.


Comment: I am confused by Bjorn's previous comment: on the one hand, the f he gives does have determinant $\pm 1$.  On the other hand, for any n the sum of n squares form has determinant 1 and is not smooth over 2.

Comment: Pete: the f Bjorn gives has determinant 2. The extra x^2 term contributes a lower right entry of 2. The sum of n squares has det 2^n so it's not surprising it's singular at 2 for n>=1. But I'm also confused. If the det vanishes mod p then surely the fibre at p is singular because we can find an element of the kernel and this will be a singular point.

Comment: Oh, I see what Bjorn is saying. The point is that if all the partial derivates vanish you can't deduce that f vanishes, because the usual trick doen't work for a degree 2 equation in characteristic 2. So my "singular point" might not lie on the variety!


Comment: @buzzard: Thanks for your explanation.  I was (mistakenly) computing the determinant in the sense of quadratic forms, not the Jacobian determinant.  I'll leave my comment because others might have done the same.

Comment: Very nice. It would be even nicer if someone can come up with an example having non-trivial fundamental group.

Comment: As Minhyong pointed out to me via email, this has nothing to do with sections: this is just another question! Is there a smooth proper variety over Z with non-trivial fund gp? Take the product of this with a smooth proper variety with no sections if you want one with no sections. The problem is that no-one will see this question ;-) Minhyong---you should ask another question! Maybe flag varieties do the job again.

Comment: @moonface: A reductive $\mathbf{Z}$-group $G$ with $G(\mathbf{R})$ compact has no proper parabolic $\mathbf{Z}$-subgroup since it has none over $\mathbf{Q}$ (by $\mathbf{Q}$-anisotropicity).  So the comments about flag varieties are unclear: the quadratic lattice $(L,q)$ gives rise to a smooth projective quadric $V = (q=0) \subset \mathbf{P}(L^{\ast})$ over $\mathbf{Z}$ and semisimple $\mathbf{Z}$-group ${\rm{PGO}}(q)={\rm{Aut}}_{V/\mathbf{Z}}$, but how are you proposing to build the former given *only* the latter $\mathbf{Z}$-group (or more general such $G$)?